# Pulsed Power Charging Resistor and Choke

Tags: power-supply, high-voltage, radar

I am currently attempting to build a pulsed power supply that requires an 8 H inductor to produce 50 kV 17 A square pulses with widths of 100 uS. Please see the attached schematic for more details (unfortunately, the load is comprised of a gas ionizing device, thus, the resistance fluctuates quite unpredictably).

Due to the obscurely high inductance required, I have considered using a charging resistor instead. However, I am unsure of how to find the exact resistance that will be needed to match the pulse-limiting capabilities of the 8 H inductor. How many I calculate the needed resistance?

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2foOXAb.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: A capacitor discharge schema like this will NEVER produce a square wave output since it operates using the ringing of C1,L1 and the transformer inductance. Can you explain your needs (specification) somewhat better?

Comment: Greetings, the purpose is to use the above apparatus to provide 10 pulses per second where each pulse has a pulse width (lasts for) 100 uS and has a  voltage of -50 kV and current of 17 A. These are the only absolutely necessary needs. I agree that it won't be perfectly square, however, I will try to keep the gauges as high as possible on the transformer to get it to have a fast lead time. As for the goal, I am curious what value of resistor could replace L1 to give me the pulse width and frequency I had mentioned earlier.

Comment: The pulse rate is set by your thyristor pulses of course, your only limitation s how fast you can charge C1. That is a simple RC delay problem: http://www.mustcalculate.com/electronics/capacitorchargeanddischarge.php?vfrom=0&vto=9000&vs=10000&c=.0001&r=&time=.1

Comment: Too quite on the Enter key. Your bigest problem is the power in the resistor if you are really using a 1uF storage capacitor. Have you done any calculations at all on what you want to achieve?

Comment: Greetings, nothing yet for the resistor because I do not have the required equations/knowledge to do so. Currently, this model is copied from an older design used for a similar load. There is someone advising me on the rest of the device, however, he is away at the moment and I want to find out what is required for the resistor. The rest, however, was said to work.

Comment: Consider a modern SMPS to get your HV DC bus, and use bulk capacitors and a HV FET to switch a pulse through your transformer (Maybe increase the turns ratio also)? Then it is 100% customizable to engineer an optimal system... My guess is it would be on par cost wise with what your trying to do.